# C99 Macro Expansion for Struct Member Access

Tags: c, macros, c99, variadic-macros

Is it possible to do a nullity check and an access in a macro?

Eg:

```
#define LOG(mystruct, severity, format, ...) ({ \
  severity_t current = ERROR; \
  if (mystruct) { \
    current = mystruct->error_level; \
  } \
  if (severity >= current) { \
   ... //handle logging 
  } \
})
```

If I call this with `LOG(NULL, DEBUG, "test %s", "one");` I get an error as such:

`error: member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union
       note: expanded from macro 'LOG'
       current = mystruct->error_level;`

mystruct is defined as:

```
typedef struct mystruct_t {
  severity_t error_level;
}
```

I want to allow the possibility of working with a NULL `mystruct`. Eg: case of when there is an error creating the structure itself.

Comment: `NULL->error_level` is not compilable. Perhaps you could use `MYSTRUCT *ptr = (severity);` earlier on, and then `if ( ptr ) current = ptr->error_level;`

Comment: An inline function would be tidier

Comment: Let me clarify the structures a little. `mystruct_t` is a superstructure in that it contains a `severity_t`. I want to allow the possibility to handle a NULL for `mystruct` (eg: when there is say an error during the creation of a `mystruct_t` itself)

Comment: And can't inline: variadic params

Comment: You can inline variadic params, and my suggested code allows `NULL` to be used as argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that although the first branch will never been taken, `NULL` hasn't the correct type to do a `->error_level`.

You can avoid that by giving it the right type. I would do that with a local variable, not a cast so you'd capture wrong use cases of your macro. Just add

```
yourType* myStr = mystruct;
current = myStr->error_level;
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do a nullity check and an access in a macro?

Nope, the preprocessor is doing simple text replacement. It doesn't support conditionals inside the definition of a macro.

When you use the macro with `LOG(NULL, DEBUG, "test %s", "one");`, the fourth line expands to

```
current = NULL->error_level;
```

and since `NULL` is typically defined as `#define NULL ((void *)0)`, that further expands to

```
current = ((void *)0)->error_level;
```

which is why you get the message about `void` not being a structure or union.

---

To fix the problem, don't pass `NULL` to the macro, pass the pointer that contains `NULL` to the macro, e.g.

```
mystruct_t *ptr = malloc(...);
if ( !ptr )
    LOG( ptr, DEBUG, "no memory" );
```